# Log4j2 - logging to dynamically created directories

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

My app outputs some files to dynamically created directory with a name determined by System.currentTimeMillis() every time it runs.

Tried the following solution:

```
<File name="File" fileName=".\xxx\${sys:log4j2.saveDirectory}\test.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">\
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
</File>
```

In java code I call:

```
String path = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.setProperty("log4j2.saveDirectory", path);
```

but this does not work, as I get **`FileNotFoundException`**. What is a way to tell log4j2 to log in this kind of dynamically created folder?

Comment: Can you check whether the directory to try to write the log to exist/is created?

Comment: Problem solved, missed that logger was initialized before property was set

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I was calling

```
System.setProperty("log4j2.saveDirectory", path);
```

after logger initialization. Solution is to do it before initializing logger or set default path.